# Why is this XSLT transform not being applied to the XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working with this representative XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <group name="group1">
    <control name="control1.1">
      <p>Content1</p>
    </control>
    <control name="control1.2">
      <prop name="required" value="true"/>
      <p>Content2</p>
    </control>
  </group>
  <group name="group2">
    <control name="control2.1">
      <prop name="required" value="true"/>
      <p>Content1</p>
    </control>
    <control name="control2.2">
      <p>Content2</p>
    </control>
  </group>
</catalog>
```

And I am applying the following XSL that "should" be only preserving the controls with a required property (1.2 and 2.1) and dropping the rest, retaining the original XML structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="control">
    <xsl:if test="prop[@name='required']">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I process the above XSL, I get the entirety of the XML back with no transforms.  I have tried a wide variety of variations, testing different cases (including `<xsl:template match="control"/>` which should have dropped every control element), but nothing makes a dent.  I feel like the global identity transform is somehow ignoring the control transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the result

```
<catalog>
  <group name="group1">
    
    <control name="control1.2">
      <prop name="required" value="true" />
      <p>Content2</p>
    </control>
  </group>
  <group name="group2">
    <control name="control2.1">
      <prop name="required" value="true" />
      <p>Content1</p>
    </control>
    
  </group>
</catalog>
```

with your two samples.

Any chance your real XML has a (default) namespace declaration you didn't show?

Posting this as an answer for the time being as the samples don't fit well into a comment; will delete it if more details show the cause of the problem.

Anyway, I would suggest to solely use the identity transformation template plus an empty one for the elements you don't want to be copied:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="control[not(prop[@name='required'])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But that won't solve the problem you seem to experience and usually is a namespace problem.

Comment: Thank you Martin--you are right, there is a namespace issue (interesting because the same xmlns is referenced in both the XML and XSL, but I'll dig into that further).  But I am also taking your recommendation on cleaning up the control template.